# Keras model predicting wrong values(accuracy: 0.0000e+00)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, data-science

Que the cliche "This is my first Keras project", but alas, this is the truth. I apologize for any cringe beginner mistakes in advance.

**How is the data setup**

Column A: We capture the time a given train is scheduled to depart in 24-hour time format.

Column B: An integer representation of the given trains destination. EX California == 2, New York == 0

Column C: The track assigned to the given train.

[Screenshot of data setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VB5cP.png)

**GOAL**

By using this data, can we predict the track number using the time and location.

**Current Attempt**

```html
# multivariate one step problem
from numpy import array
from numpy import hstack
from numpy import insert
from numpy import zeros,newaxis
from numpy import reshape
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator
import pandas as pd


file_name  = "DATA_DUMP.csv"
destination = 0
departure = 1622

#extract values
raw_data  = pd.read_csv(file_name)
data   = raw_data

in_seq1  = array([data['TIME'].values])
in_seq2  = array([data['LOCATION'].values])
result  = array([data['TRACK'][0:-1].values])

# reshape series
in_seq1  = in_seq1.reshape((in_seq1.shape[1],len(in_seq1)))
in_seq2  = in_seq2.reshape((in_seq2.shape[1],len(in_seq2)))
result  = result.reshape((result.shape[1],len(result)))

dataset  = hstack((in_seq1, in_seq2))
result  = insert(result,0,0)
result  = result.reshape((len(result),1))

# define generator
n_features  = dataset.shape[1]
n_input  = 1
generator  = TimeseriesGenerator(dataset, result, length=n_input, batch_size=1)

for i in range(len(generator)):
 x, y = generator[i]
 print('%s => %s' % (x, y))

# define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, activation='sigmoid', input_shape=(n_input, n_features)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.00001), loss='mse',metrics=['accuracy'])
# fit model

model.fit_generator(generator, steps_per_epoch=1, epochs=500, verbose=2)
# make a one step prediction out of sample

raw_array = array([1507,3]) #predict arrival at 15:07 destination 3, what track will it be?

x_input = array(raw_array).reshape((1,n_input,n_features))

yhat = model.predict(x_input, verbose=1)
print(yhat)
```

**The Problem**

Although my code runs, I am getting *extremely* inaccurate predictions. I'm assuming this is due to my large loss. Any help in getting this model up and running would be greatly appreciated.

`Epoch 500/500
1/1 - 0s - loss: 424.2032 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00`

Comment: Him I think you should use the metric mae, so instead of `metrics=['accuracy']` , try `metrics=['mae']`, because the accuracy metric is used on classification tasks.Try it and post the mae scores if you like.[mae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_error)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @George. Here's the result after changing it. `Epoch 500/500
1/1 - 0s - loss: 357.8508 - mae: 18.9169` The out of sample test resulted in `[[0.07617366]]` which isn't accurate still

Comment: Try this setup:`model.add(LSTM(200, input_shape=(n_input, n_features)))`
`model.add(Dense(1))`
`model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001), loss='mse',metrics=['mae'])`, remove the sigmoid activation , you don't want that.reduce the lr and increase units.Result now is `[[15.455093]]`